# how to access property of a custom control in XAML WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom `MyButton` with a `Text` property:

```
public string Text
{
    get { return aTextBlockInButton.Text; }
    set { aTextBlockInButton.Text = value; }
}
```

Creating a button in C# and setting its `Text` property works (Text shows up correctly):

```
MyButton b = new MyButton(); 
b.Text="hello";
```

However, when I do this in XAML

```
<local:MyButton Text="someText" />
```

I get the error

```
the member "Text" is not recognized or is not accessible.
```

Why? Note that `MyButton` shows up in Intellisense.

Comment: have you actually tried running your code? don't believe in what XAML editor tells you. Sometimes it reports wrong (that's actually buggy).

Comment: @king wow, you are right! i wanna cry now...

Comment: @king would you post your comment, so i can mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XAML editor is actually buggy. Sometimes it does not report correctly and gives incorrect error notification. So you should not always believe in what XAML editor tells you. I even had a very long XAML code but ***the whole*** code was reported with some problem inside XAML editor, however running/debugging the code anyway is OK. So my advice is believe in yourself first, if there is any actual error, you won't be able to compile and run it.

Sometimes after running the code, coming back to the XAML code, you'll see the error notification has gone away.

Comment: I actually chaged other part of the code so i knew it wouldn't compile. but, the XAML error always showed up during the compilation along with other errors, which made me believe that error prevented compilation. After you comment, I fixed other parts and it compiled successfully, and that XAML error went away aftewards.

Answer (score 1):

You need a dependency property, normal properties wont work on XAML binding.

something like this

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(Button));
public string Text
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetValue(TextProperty) as string;
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }
}
```

read more about dependency property here: [Dependency Property Tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html)

Comment: he just sets properties, does not use Binding at all. Think about the `Point` structure, it has 2 properties `X` and `Y`. Both are not dependency properties but you can set them normally inside XAML code.

Comment: @Ronald thanks for bringing up binding. do you mean `typeof(MyButton)`? if i want to this `Text` to show up in a `TextBlock` that resides within `MyButton`, should I define a callback method? I tried it but the method must be static, which cannot reference `aTextBlock.Text`...

Comment: @Ronald never mind, just saw that the static method takes the `DependencyObject` as an argument, which is the current instance.